# array_diff not returning what's expected

Tags: php, arrays

I've read some tutorials on here but none of them return what I need. I have two arrays.

```
$arrayA = array(1960,1961,1963,1962,1954,1953,1957,1956,1955);
$arrayB = array(1949,1960,1961,1963,1962,1954,1953,1957,1956,1955);
```

However, when I run array_diff, it returns an empty array.

```
$diff = array_diff($arrayA, $arrayB);
```

But I'd like it to return 1949. What's the error in my code?

edit: since switching the variables won't work, i did var_dump for the 3 arrays (A, B, and diff) and here's the pastebin http://pastebin.com/tn1dvCs3

Comment: 1949 is in both of the arrays in pastebin.  What is the expected output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`array_diff` works by finding the elements in the first array that aren't in the second, per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). Try inverting your call:

```
$diff = array_diff($arrayB, $arrayA);
```

To see this in action, lets look at a more manageable but equivalent example:

```
$arrayA = array(1960);
$arrayB = array(1949,1960);

$diff = array_diff($arrayB, $arrayA);
var_dump($diff);
```

This yields:

```
[mylogin@aserver ~]$ vim test.php
[mylogin@aserver ~]$ php test.php
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(1949)
}
```

Please note that this uses a minimal demonstrative example of the functionality you're attempting to get. By discarding unnecessary data in your actual implementation you can more quickly zero in on the problem you're having.

Comment: still returning an empty array for me. i updated the main post with more info

Comment: @user2036066 I have tested this code, as shown above, and it works. Your pastebin shows two arrays with no diff: they contain the same elements, so naturally this won't yield anything.

Answer (score 2):

> Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

Therefore:

```
$diff = array_diff($arrayB, $arrayA);
```

will give you the result you're after.

Comment: Still returning an empty array for me

Answer (score 1):

Swap variables in `array_diff` call:

```
<?php
$arrayA = array(1960,1961,1963,1962,1954,1953,1957,1956,1955);
$arrayB = array(1949,1960,1961,1963,1962,1954,1953,1957,1956,1955);

$diff = array_diff($arrayB, $arrayA);

var_dump($diff);
?>
```

Shows:

```
array(1) { [0]=> int(1949) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Give,

```
$diff = array_diff($arrayB, $arrayA);
```

To have result of `1949`, ie the element `$arrayB` has and `$arrayA` has not.

ie

```
$arrayA = array(1960,1961,1963,1962,1954,1953,1957,1956,1955);
$arrayB = array(1949,1960,1961,1963,1962,1954,1953,1957,1956,1955);

$diff = array_diff($arrayB, $arrayA);

print_r($diff );
```

[Test Here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)

Answer (score 0):

you can read document here http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php

```
$diff = array_diff($arrayB, $arrayA);
print_r($diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = '5,6,'; 
$b = '6,6,'; 
$a_array = explode(',',$a); 
$b_array = explode(',',$b);
$result = array_diff($b_array,$a_array); 
var_dump($result);
```

However, when I run array_diff, it returns an empty array.

```
$result = array_diff($b_array,$a_array);
```

But I'd like it to return 6. What's the error in my code?